# Suppress warnings on import?

Tags: python, warnings, python-import, python-interactive

Assuming I write a python package that has to use the `imp` module, and my package is "TestModule" which is the following:

```
import imp
import pip
import sys

def update_and_reload(module, *args, **kwargs):
    pip.main(['install', module, '--upgrade', '--user'])
    return imp.reload(module)
```

When I do `import TestModule` in the terminal, I get a pending deprecation warning on `imp`. How would I make `imp`'s warning not occur / filter out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could use the [`warning`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) module:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    import imp
import pip
...
```